# MPLAB IDE data type sizes

Tags: c, size, mplab, size-type

In MPLAB IDE what is the sizes of data types (`int`, `unsigned int`, `float`, `unsigned float`, `char`...)?

Answer (score 8):

This is hard without knowing for which CPU you want to compile code. Assuming e.g. Microchip's C18 compiler for the PIC18, the [User Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/C18_User_Guide_51288j.pdf) states the following fundamental type sizes:

```
TYPE                SIZE     RANGE
char(1,2)            8 bits  -128 127
signed char          8 bits  -128 127
unsigned char        8 bits  0 255
int                 16 bits  -32,768 32,767
unsigned int        16 bits  0 65,535
short               16 bits  -32,768 32,767
unsigned short      16 bits  0 65,535
short long          24 bits  -8,388,608 8,388,607
unsigned short long 24 bits  0 16,777,215
long                32 bits  -2,147,483,648 2,147,483,647
unsigned long       32 bits  0 4,294,967,295
```

Note that this includes some types (`short long`) that are not standard in C.

Comment: Can I suggest that you state that these values are for Microchip's C18 compiler for the PIC18 family? I know the linked user guide provides that information, but it would make this answer more complete to include it here as well. Also, given that the question doesn't specify a compiler and target microcontroller, it should be stressed that the types may be different sizes for other targets.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the implementation of integer data types on different MPLAB XC compilers.

1. Data Types for 8-bit devices (implementation on XC8 compiler):
   [image]
2. Data Types for 16-bit devices (implementation on XC16 compiler):
   [image]
3. Data Types for 32-bit devices (implementation on XC32 compiler):[image]

Answer (score 2):

Values for int, long, etc., are never standardly defined across all compilers([reference](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52053B.pdf)) . For this reason, it is advised to make use of the library:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

To make use of this library for your own purposes, try using the code as follows:

```
typedef uint8_t    BYTE
typedef uint16_t   WORD
typedef uint32_t   LONG
```

Then you just use these to define your variables. This method usually makes use of an integer.h file to store these definitions and is included wherever needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would be wary of such generalizations. MPLAB is just an IDE - it is suitable for different chips. Microchip has 8-bit controllers like PIC18F, 16-bit and 32-bit controllers. The data types for each may be different and hold serious implications for performance. I.e. for the 8-bit chips the 16 and 32 bit data types may be emulated in software, which isn't always what you want.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<stdint.h>
long x;
```

These two things helped me get through ;)
And the rest info. is already shared by other folks.